# When to use "подви́гаться" and when to use "подвига́ться"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> It did me a lot of good to **move my body a little** after sitting for one whole day.

I assume that with this specific meaning you should use "(немного) **подви́гаться**", but how does "**подвига́ться**" compare?

I wonder if "**подви́гаться**" denotes multi-directional random movements, with an emphasis placed on the idea "for a while / a little" due to the prefix "по-", whereas "**подвига́ться**" refers to a movement in a single direction, as in "moving forward" or figuratively "advancing (upwards) in your career".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pretty much nailed it on your own save for a few points.

**подвигАться** a person can only physically and in any direction, when someone wishes to sit down next to you on a limited sitting space they might ask you to **подвинуться** which would be sideways.

With regard to career it's **пРодвигаться**, which is always a progressing movement, in the direction you're facing (in a physical sense) or invest efforts in, a movement towards specific destination.

Comment: Author definitely has "подвигАться" in the meaning of "подвинуться на [некое свершение]".

Comment: @Alexander i interpreted it as a misreading of the verb's meaning, because the way it's described by him points at the meaning of **пРодвигАться**, we don't ***подвигаемся по карьерной лестнице***, but **пРодвигаемся**, besides i believe this is the first time i come across such use of the word **подвигАться** and although it's not totally unthinkable, it must be extremely rare for the modern language, indeed there's the word **подвиг** but its corresponding verb, if there was any, is not in active use, in the sense of **свершение** i'm aware of **подвиЗаться** and **сподвигнуть**

Comment: neither the [dictionary of Church-Slavonic and Russian from 1847](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=XB9fAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=z92QELVDfU&sig=ZInmUFfvU2NmQMGF6dwBqivucSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXwt_itPrZAhURsaQKHcoeC2E4ChDoAQhbMAk#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&f=false) is aware of such use of the verb **подвигАться**, despite it sounding archaic

Comment: There is also a grammatical difference: **подви́гаться** is perfective, while **подвига́ться** is imperfective.

Comment: Indeed **,подвига́ться** is very rare. Here is an example of when you might use it: Я попросил его подвинуться, но он не желает подвига́ться.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov i was referring to its unlikely use in the phrase **подвинуться на [некое свершение]** mentioned by Alexander

Answer (score 1):

Source **Большой толковый словарь русского языка (Кузнецов)**, 2014 edition gives the following meanings.

> ПОДВ**И**ГАТЬСЯ, -аюсь, -аешься; св. Двигаться некоторое время, сделать несколько движений. Дайте ребёнку п.  My transl.: move for a while, make several movements.

which is close to your suggestion (multi-directional random movements).

As for ПОДВИГ**А**ТЬСЯ this source says to see ПОДВИНУТЬСЯ (because ПОДВИГ**А**ТЬСЯ is its **imperfective**)

> **ПОДВИНУТЬСЯ**, -нусь, -нешься; св. 1. Несколько, немного придвинуться или передвинуться. Все немножко подвинулись. Туча подвинулась к нам. 2. Пройти, проехать вперёд; продвинуться. Лодка подвинулась вверх по течению. // Идти, продвигаться вперёд (о войсках, фронте и т.п.). Фронт подвинулся южнее. 3. Несколько, немного продвинуться, приблизиться к завершению, к поставленной цели. П. в немецком языке. Строительство подвинулось. 4. Разг. Преуспеть на службе, получить повышение; повыситься (по службе, общественному положению и т.п.). П. в чинах. <*Подвиг**а**ться*, -аюсь, -аешься; нсв.

Brief translation for ПОДВИНУТЬСЯ: 1. Move a little. 2. Go forward, move forward. 3. Progress, move closer to the end, improve. 4. *Informal*,  Advance in career (status, etc.). The final abbreviation *нсв* = imperfective.

So you are basically right in your suggestions. Except the 'career' meaning which is really not used often and sounds somewhat old-fashioned (a commonly used alternative is *продвинуться*).